# Calling API endpoint inside docker container

Tags: docker, nginx, dockerfile

I have a small express application running inside a docker container. The endpoint is accessible locally through `http://localhost:8888/api/run` . The docker container was run using this command:

```
docker run -dp 8888:8888 code-editor
```

I configured NGINX to serve the response from docker using the location block:

server {

```
    server_name www.baseURL.tech baseURL.tech;
      -------------------CONNECT WITH APP INSIDE DOCKER--------------------
    location /compiler {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8888/;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }

     -------------------CONNECT WITH MAIN NODE APP--------------------
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
```

The path being called is `https://baseURL/compiler/api/run` as an ajax request from the main website `https://baseURL` but it is returning 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
location /compiler
```

which results in Nginx passing on the entire URL, i.e. `compiler/api/run` to the Express app.
You want it to remove the `compiler` part and the easiest way to do that is to add a slash at the end of the location, like this

```
location /compiler/
```

Then Nginx will only pass on `api/run` to Express.

Comment: Thanks. Any documentation regarding this?

Comment: I feel the Nginx docs are pretty bad, but maybe you're better at reading them than I am. Look here https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location and here https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass